# ¿Cómo redireccionar mi página web según el navegador que esté usando con Laravel?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera que al usar Internet Explorer mi app me pueda redireccionar a otro sitio que contenga algún tipo de mensaje o algo recomendandome usar otro navegador. Estoy usando Laravel.. quisiera que la app funcionara con todos los navegadores excepto con internet explorer.

Comment: Pregunta editada pues la misma y su solución no tienen que ver con Laravel o PHP

Comment: LA pregunta está limitada por el creador a una solucion para laravel (php). Por lo tnto las etiquetas originales son correctas.

Comment: Yo no veo donde tiene algo que ver Laravel, si el OP. Lo ocupa en Laravel que agregue lo que ha tratado y lo explique mejor

Comment: Entonces tengo un problema de comprensión, pues lo veo en el título y también en el texto descriptivo...

Comment: Ojo que también hay una opción sólo con PHP para lo que pidió el OP y quizás incluso existe un método de Laravel (esto último no estoy seguro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realizando una comprobación con javascript puedes saber si el usuario está utilizando IE:

```
// Internet Explorer 6-11
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
// Edge 20+
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

if(isIE || isEdge){
    window.location.replace("http://www.example.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para futuras referencias además de Javascript también puedes hacerlo con PHP, existe una función llamada `get_browser` que te devuelve información relacionada al navegador en el que está ejecutándose tu aplicación.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

También puedes leer la variable superglobal `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` y procesar el texto para tener información de tu navegador.

Comment: gracias por la información